# Python custom empty scale overwrite to 1,1,1

Tags: python, transforms

Python custom empty scale overwrite to 1,1,1
for primitives it work fine but for empty for some reason it`s overwrites to default 1 any idea why ?

```
import bpy
size=(3,3,3)
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=size)
```

Comment: Also FYI you can add an empty without `ops` this way https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/51291/86891

Comment: What's also interesting is the docs say the default `scale` value is `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` while it would make more sense to be `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`...

Comment: try: (from mathutils)
size = Vector((3,3,3))

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a bug.

What works:

```
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', align='WORLD', location=(1, 0, 0), scale=(2,2,2))

bpy.context.object.scale = (2,2,2)
```