# Editing an origins rotation based on a given quaternian using matrix math

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was any way to change the orientation/rotation of an objects origin without changing the actual mesh?

I've got this bit of code, which gets the rotation value I want the object to inherit... but I have no clue how I would actually go about applying it to the object.

```
    import bpy, bmesh

    ob = bpy.context.object

    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(ob.data) # Only works in Edit Mode
    bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
    bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
    
    active_geo = bm.select_history.active
    if active_geo is not None:
        _loc, rot, _scl = ob.matrix_world.decompose()
        rot_matrix = rot.to_matrix().to_4x4()

        direction_vec = rot_matrix @ (active_geo.verts[0].co - active_geo.verts[1].co)

        normal_quat = direction_vec.to_track_quat('Z', 'Y')
        normal_euler = normal_quat.to_euler('XYZ')

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='ARROWS', align='WORLD', rotation=normal_euler, scale=(1, 1, 1))
```

The empty that gets added is representative of the orientation I want the cubes origin to have while keeping the mesh the same.

[image: Script result with 3D Cursor in the correct position]

Below is an example of how I can brute force the same effect I am looking for by enabling **Affect Only Origins**, and using **Align Rotation to Target** with snapping.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MCsx.jpg

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You do know about object rotation, right?

Comment: Yes, I do. My question is about changing the objects rotation without actually rotating the mesh.

Comment: bpy.data.objects[“CubeThing”].rotation_euler

Comment: _without_ rotating the actual mesh, I want to change the pivots orient so the local space can be set up properly.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230321/rotate-origin-only-to-match-other-object-rotation

I found this example, but the use case is different and I had trouble applying it in this specific context.

Comment: The object rotation does not rotate the actual mesh within the object space. If you want to change where the origin is, you either have to translate the mesh within the object space, or you have to parent the object to an empty and use that as an “origin” instead.

Comment: Apologies, I updated my last comment to include an example.

Comment: Does this work? (1) Apply the current transform, if any (2) Set the object's transform to the inverse of the one you want (3) Apply the current transform (4) Set the object's transform to the one you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you need is as simple as:

1. Save current vertex positions in the world space (multiply local coords by `ob.matrix_world`).
2. Do whatever you want to do, it seems you figured it out because you can align the empty the way you want, but also apply that to the object.
3. Since changing the object's transformation matrix will move vertices in the world space, restore their positions to the same world space as in p. 1. - so set local coords to saved copy of world space, multiplied by `ob.matrix_world.inversed()`.

```py
import bpy, bmesh
from bpy import context as C

ob = C.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
mat = ob.matrix_world

# an error is better than the script failing silently
co0, co1 = map(lambda x:x.co, bm.select_history.active.verts[:2])
direction = co1 - co0

_loc, rot, _scl = mat.decompose()
rot_matrix = rot.to_matrix().to_4x4()
direction_vec = rot_matrix @ direction
normal_quat = direction_vec.to_track_quat('Z', 'Y')
normal_euler = normal_quat.to_euler('XYZ')

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='ARROWS', align='WORLD', rotation=normal_euler, scale=(1, 1, 1))

# save in world space
coords = [mat @ v.co for v in me.vertices]

# maybe you want to position your empty
C.object.location = mat @ (co0 + co1) / 2

# easiest way to apply new rotation
ob.rotation_euler = normal_euler
C.view_layer.update()

# restore to old world space
mat_inv = ob.matrix_world.inverted()
for v, prev_co in zip(me.vertices, coords):
    v.co = mat_inv @ prev_co
```

I don't understand everything you're trying to do, so maybe the code could be improved - for example, you multiply `direction` by only rotation matrix - but what if the scales aren't uniform? Why not simply multiply it by `mat`?

### V2

Less readable but faster code:

```py
import bpy, bmesh
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import Matrix

ob = C.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
mat = ob.matrix_world

# an error is better than the script failing silently
co0, co1 = map(lambda x:mat @ x.co, bm.select_history.active.verts[:2])
normal_quat = (co1 - co0).to_track_quat('Z', 'Y')
normal_euler = normal_quat.to_euler('XYZ')

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='ARROWS', align='WORLD', rotation=normal_euler, scale=(1, 1, 1))

# maybe you want to position your empty
C.object.location = (co0 + co1) / 2

# make local space = world space
me.transform(mat)

# a faster way to calculate new matrix - without refreshing the View Layer
t, _, s = mat.decompose()
T = Matrix.Translation(t)
R = normal_euler.to_matrix().to_4x4()
S = Matrix.Diagonal(s.to_4d())
ob.matrix_world = T @ R @ S

# now apply the inverted matrix on the mesh
me.transform(ob.matrix_world.inverted())
```

### V3

The below solution never exits *Edit Mode* and applies only a single transform:

```py
import bpy, bmesh
from bpy import context as C, data as D
from mathutils import Matrix

ob = C.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
mat = ob.matrix_world

co0, co1 = map(lambda x:mat @ x.co, bm.select_history.active.verts[:2])
normal_quat = (co1 - co0).to_track_quat('Z', 'Y')
normal_euler = normal_quat.to_euler('XYZ')

t, r, s = mat.decompose()
quat_diff = normal_quat.rotation_difference(r)
mat_diff = quat_diff.to_matrix().to_4x4()
T = Matrix.Translation(t)
R = normal_euler.to_matrix().to_4x4()
S = Matrix.Diagonal(s.to_4d())
ob.matrix_world = T @ R @ S

# add empty without going to Object mode
# https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/51291/60486
empty = D.objects.new("empty", None)
C.scene.collection.objects.link(empty)
empty.empty_display_size = 2
empty.empty_display_type = 'ARROWS'
empty.empty_display_size = 1
empty.rotation_euler = normal_euler
empty.location = (co0 + co1) / 2

def slow():
    """possibly slower, but stays in edit mode"""
    bm.transform(mat_diff)  # transform only once
    for f in bm.faces:
        f.normal_update()
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)

def fast():
    """possibly faster, but switches modes"""
    global bm  # to write to it
    bm.transform(mat_diff)  # transform only once
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

def best():
    """Probably the best of both worlds"""
    bm.transform(mat_diff)  # transform only once
    bmesh.ops.recalc_face_normals(bm, faces=bm.faces)
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)

# if it really is slow or fast probably depends on the amount
# of geometry and for small geos doesn't matter
best()
```

Comment: Yeah apologies, I don't really know much about matrix math so my code example is more or less what I scrounged up from the internet. The new empty was created for visualization of the rotation I want the object to inherit, but it may have been confusing.

This solution works for my needs so it's probably worthy of confirming as the solution, but it also seems particularly slow? Is there a more efficient solution than saving the global vertex positions? Based on [this](https://bit.ly/3wKMkyt) I assumed there may be a method that just involves inversion of the applied transform? Thanks again.

Comment: @razed you have to modify vertex data if you want the vertices to stay in words space while moving their container. There are faster ways to modify the vertices, like the one I just added, there's also a possibility to use numpy.

Comment: What does container mean in this context? Is it the origin? Also, this code seems to get the wrong location for the empty, and the wrong rotation if you don't decompose the matrix before getting `direction_vec`. Image example [here](https://imgur.com/a/5n2YsNi) (this example is on an object with un-applied location & rotation)

Comment: @razed see updated code.

Comment: I've marked it as the answer as its everything I need... But I was wondering why the switch to object mode is required? (besides for creating the empty). I tried using it without the mode switch and the `me.transform()` stuff seems to not work.

Comment: @razed `me.transform()` modifies the mesh data, however `bmesh` creates a temporary copy of that data and operates on that. Once you go back to object mode, the `bmesh` copy is saved back to the mesh data. Think of that as `a = Vector((0, 1, 2)); b = a.copy(); a *= 2; a = b` - whatever you replace the third statement (`a *= 2`) with, doesn't matter, because `a` will be overridden with the temporary copy.

Comment: So would you say its possible to do this operation _without_ the context switch? I tried using `bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)` in various locations without the context switch code and it didn't seem to work. Maybe the wrong function to use or something.

Comment: @razed you certainly can do that without going to Edit Mode, though if you want to select an edge in edit mode, then you can't use the `transform` method. Since `bmesh` also doesn't have `foreach_set`, I don't think you can make a fast transformation there (well, there are ways, but nothing trivia,l I think). And apparently, since you complained on the speed, there's too much geometry to just use a Python's list comprehension.

Comment: Sorry I mean while IN edit mode, this hypothetical operator is based on being in edit mode when it is used.

Comment: @razed you can use `bmesh.transform()`, but then you will have to recalculate normals...